# 504 Gateway Time-out all the time

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2

I get this error when I try to use nginx as a reverce proxy server for apache. I guess I have something wrong with nginx side of configuration because when I access the web-host with port I use for apache, everything works nice.
So, here is my nginx configuration file for host:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name my-site;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/my-site/myapp/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /var/www/my-site/myapp/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-site:8000;
    }
}
```

Here's my error log for nginx, it wasn't any useful for me though:

```
2014/02/22 13:58:37 [error] 1398#0: *10 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: my-site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/", host: "my-site"
2014/02/22 14:01:40 [error] 1398#0: *14 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: my-site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/", host: "my-site"
2014/02/22 14:10:29 [error] 1609#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: my-site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/", host: "my-site"
2014/02/22 19:07:59 [error] 647#0: *176 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: my-site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/", host: "my-site"
2014/02/23 13:40:35 [error] 647#0: *650 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: my-site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/", host: "my-site"
```

I've read somewhere that it may happen when load is too big, but in my case this is definitely not it.

Comment: Maybe better asked on ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Apache bound to port 8000?

Have you made sure that you can access port 8000 with the external IP address associated to your domain? You can do this by retrieving a page with the `http://my-site:8000` URL on the server.

You could try using

```
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
```

instead of my-site:8000;

This way you don't need the ability to connect to your site via your external IP.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000 is bound to default record. I don't get any error though.

Comment: If your Apache is bound to 127.0.0.1:8000, you cannot access it via the external IP (my-site) defined in nginx. Then you must use the proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000; statement in nginx config.